# How to kill parallel execution of Databricks notebooks?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, databricks, dbutils

I am currently using Python's `Threading` to parallelize the execution of multiple Databricks notebooks. These are long-running notebooks, and I need to add some logic for killing the threads in the case where I want to restart the execution with new changes. When re-executing the master notebook without killing the threads, the cluster is quickly filled with computational heavy, long-lived threads, leaving little space for the actually required computations.

I have tried [these](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) suggestions without luck. Furthermore, I have tried getting the runId from `dbutils.notebook.run()` and killing the thread with `dbutils.notebook.exit(runId)`, but since the call to `dbutils.notebook.run()` is synchronous, I am unable to obtain the runId before the notebook has executed.

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Hello @sondrelv and thank you for your question.  I would like to clarify that `dbutils.notebook.exit(value)` is not used for killing other threads by runId.  `dbutils.notebook.exit(value)` is used to cause the current (this) thread to exit and return a value.
I see the difficulty of management [without an available interrupt](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17597/accessing-ephemeral-notebook-through-run-id.html) inside notebook code.  Given this limitation, I have tried to look for other ways to cancel the threads.

One way is to use other utilities to kill the thread/run.

Part of the difficulty in solving this, is that threads/runs created through `dbutils.notebook.run()` are ephemeral runs.  The Databricks CLI `databricks runs get --run-id <ephemeral_run_id>` can fetch details of an ephemeral run.  If details can be fetched, then the cancel should also work (`databricks runs cancel ...`).

The remaining difficulty is getting the run ids.  Ephemeral runs are excluded from the CLI runs list operation `databricks runs list`.
As you noted, the `dbutils.notebook.run()` is synchronous, and does not return a value to code until it finishes.
However, in the notbook UI, the run ID and link is printed when it starts.  There must be a way to capture these.  I have not yet found how.

Another possible solution, would be to create some endpoint or resources for the child notebooks check whether they should continue execution or exit early using `dbutils.notebooks.exit()`.  Doing this check between every few cells would be similar to the approaches in the article you linked, just applied to a notebook instead of a thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thank you for your suggestions and the clarification around usage of dbutils.notebook.exit(value). I'll do some more research on obtaining the list of runIds!